# Prove or disprove: If a,b ∈ Z, a,b > 0, and a^2|b^3, then a|b

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If a^2|b^3, then a|b.

How do I prove or disprove this using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic? Any tips?

Comment: Consider a prime $p$ and take $a=p^5, b=p^4$.

Comment: What does $a|b$ mean?

Comment: It means a divides b.

Comment: You don't need the FTA or any other theorem to DISprove a statement like that. All you need is a counter-example. The smallest counter-example is a = 8, b = 4.

Comment: I guess if you had a statement like $a^n \mid b^{n+1}$ for all $n$, then $a \mid b$. But like that, no.

Answer (score 3):

Something is not true here.

Try $a=2^4$ and $b=2^3$.

Comment: Doesn't that actually work? Doesn't that simplify to $2^8$ divides $2^9$?

Comment: @RyanGoulden Which is true, but clearly doesn't imply $2^4\mid 2^3$.

Comment: Oh man, my apologies. I was reading it as 2 divides 2, not 16 divides 8. Well I certainly feel silly now.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic: $a^2 \mid b^3$ if and only if for each prime $p$, $2 \operatorname{ord}_p(a) \le 3 \operatorname{ord}_p(b)$, and $a \mid b$ if and only if for each prime $p$, $\operatorname{ord}_p(a) \le \operatorname{ord}_p(b)$.  Now, does the first imply the second?  (It will help if you abstract out the roles of $\operatorname{ord}_p(a)$ and $\operatorname{ord}_p(b)$ and ask: does $2m \le 3n$ necessarily imply $m \le n$ for nonnegative integers $m, n$?)